# Less verbose way to write_all to a Write in Rust

Tags: io, rust

I created a helper to write all data in a slice to a `Write` type but it's very verbose and easy to get wrong. I was wondering if there's a better way to ignore the `ErrorKind::Interrupted` (from a `EINTR`).

```
fn _write_all<OutputType> (w : &mut OutputType, buf : &[u8]) -> Result<(), io::Error>
where OutputType: Write {
    let mut total_written : usize = 0;
    while total_written < buf.len() {
        match w.write(&buf[total_written..]) {
            Err(e) => {
                match e.kind() {
                    ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
                    _ => return Err(e),
                }
            },
            Ok(cur_written) => {
                if cur_written == 0 {
                     return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof, "Write EOF"));
                }
                total_written += cur_written;
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I have a feeling most users are going to use the `try!` macro and simply ignore `ErrorKind::Interrupted` and be surprised when programs start to fail simply due to a busy system with an `EINTR`.

If there's a better way to write this I would be very keen to hear about it.

A similar problem happens with input, including the nested match.

For the record, [RFC 517 (IO / OS Reform)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0517-io-os-reform.md) states that `write_all` ignores `EINTR` errors, but [the documentation for `Write::write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) mentions that `write_all` returns the first error encountered, requiring a similar loop as presented.

Comment: *If* you are looking for a review of your code, then Code Review may be a better location. Please read the [guide for Code Review for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/32521) to see if your question would make more sense over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. `std::io::Write::write_all` *does* retry if `std::io::Write::write` returns `ErrorKind::Interrupted`, as can be seen [in the source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.7.0/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L983-L994):

```
fn write_all(&mut self, mut buf: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
    while !buf.is_empty() {
        match self.write(buf) {
            Ok(0) => return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::WriteZero,
                                           "failed to write whole buffer")),
            Ok(n) => buf = &buf[n..],
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => {}
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```